Performance issues with Spring Integration SMB inbound channel adapter
I am using Spring Integration 6.0.5 and trying to configure an inbound channel adapter for smb.
I have it working and reading files but the performance is poor and I cannot seem to influence how many files are fetched in one go. There is always 7 seconds between each file getting processed and I can see in the logs regular 'SMB share init:' logs from the SmbSessionFactory. I wonder if I am creating new sessions when I shouldn't be. My Bean config looks like this.
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SMBConfig {

    private String host;

    private String domain;

    private String username;


    private String password;

    private int port;

    @Bean
    public SmbSessionFactory smbSessionFactory() {
        SmbSessionFactory smbSession = new SmbSessionFactory();
        smbSession.setHost(host);
        smbSession.setPort(port);
        smbSession.setDomain(domain);
        smbSession.setUsername(username);
        smbSession.setPassword(password);
        smbSession.setShareAndDir("sambashare");
        smbSession.setSmbMinVersion(DialectVersion.SMB210);
        smbSession.setSmbMaxVersion(DialectVersion.SMB311);
        return smbSession;
    }


    @Bean
    public SmbRemoteFileTemplate template(SmbSessionFactory smbSessionFactory) {
        return new SmbRemoteFileTemplate(smbSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "stream", outputChannel = "xml")
    public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer() {
        return new StreamTransformer("UTF-8");
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "stream", poller = @Poller(maxMessagesPerPoll = "10", fixedDelay = "1"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> smbMessageSource(CompositeFileListFilter filter, SmbRemoteFileTemplate template) {
        SmbStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SmbStreamingMessageSource(template);
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("test/");
        messageSource.setMaxFetchSize(100);
        messageSource.setFilter(filter);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeFileListFilter<SmbFile> compositeFileListFilter() {
        CompositeFileListFilter<SmbFile> filters = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
        filters.addFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
        return filters;
    }
}

And I have a ServiceActivator
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "xml")
        void serviceActivator(String xml) {

            log.info(xml);
        }


did u tested : setCacheSessions(true) and setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1); // Fetch one file per poll

I haven't tried set cache sessions, will try that now

I cannot find a cache sessions method.

Take a look into CachingSessionFactory wrapper: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/sftp/session-caching.html#page-title

I tested your conf and I think that Spring Integration recreates the SmbSessionFactory bean on every poll cycle due to the default scope (prototype). you can add @Scope("singleton") to smbSessionFactory() . Also Spring Integration provides CachingSessionFactory , consider use cache for SmbRemoteFileTemplate which depends on the SmbSessionFactory

Thanks, I will take a look but Singleton is the default scope isn't it?
